# Rails caching Time.zone.now in module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a weird error where scopes in production to not reflect the current time.

```
module TimeFilter
  # Provides scopes to filter results based on time.
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    base.class_eval do
      scope :today, where(end_time: Time.zone.now.midnight..Time.zone.now)
      scope :this_week, where(end_time: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week..Time.zone.now)
      scope :this_month, where(end_time: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now)
      scope :older_than_this_month, where("end_time < ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month)
      scope :last_month, where(end_time: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month - 1.month)
    end
  end
end
```

Time.zone.now seems to be the same time as in the rails console.

If I move the scopes from the library into my model it works without a problem. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your scopes are being evaluated once, in the `class_eval`. To correct this issue use a lambda for your scopes, like so:

```
  scope :today, lambda {where(end_time: Time.zone.now.midnight..Time.zone.now)}
  scope :this_week, lambda {where(end_time: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week..Time.zone.now)}
  scope :this_month, lambda {where(end_time: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now)}
  scope :older_than_this_month, lambda {where("end_time < ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month)}
  scope :last_month, lambda {where(end_time: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month - 1.month)}
```

That will cause the times to evaluate when the actual scope is called, not when the eval is called.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Just a question: Doesn't lambda normally require a parameter? Just trying to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Nope! Lambda is shorthand for [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) -- just like any other function, it can accept any number of arguments (including zero).